# Proving that the Gamma function infinite product definition extends its integral form definition

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

The integral form definition of the Gamma function is as follows. It is valid for all complex numbers with $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$:

$$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x} dx$$

See this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gamma_function&oldid=852575146#Main_definition) for justification.

It is well-known that the Gamma function also has this infinite product expression that is valid for all complex numbers $z$ except for the negative integers.

$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{n}} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^z\right] $$

See this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gamma_function&oldid=852575146#Euler's_definition_as_an_infinite_product) for the justification.

How do we rigorously prove that these two definitions of $\Gamma(z)$ are equivalent on their common domain $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_Form_of_Gamma_Function_equivalent_to_Euler_Form#Proof_2).

Comment: Through the dominated convergence theorem and integration by parts. Have a look at [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) around page 72.